# Error messages while doing pip install psychopy on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, spyder, psychopy

I am getting this kind of messages (image in attachment) while installing `psychopy` module in anaconda spyder 2.7 64 bit. I never got this kind of instructions before and I think because of that I am getting this sorts of error while running the code

> from pyglet.window import key: ImportError: cannot import name key
>
> cannot import name logging
>
> NameError: name ‘PUINT’ is not defined

If some one can share information to avoid this problems, would be really helpful.

Traceback:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 
215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", 
line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 
795, in install
requirement.commit_uninstall()

File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", 
line 767, in commit_uninstall
self.uninstalled.commit()
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", 
line 142, in commit
rmtree(self.save_dir)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", 
line 49, in wrapped_f
return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", 
line 212, in call
raise attempt.get()
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", 
line 247, in get
six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", 
line 200, in call
attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 
102, in rmtree
onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in rmtree
rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in rmtree
rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in rmtree
rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in rmtree
rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in rmtree
rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in rmtree
rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in rmtree
rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 266, in rmtree
onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
File "C:\Users\Ravi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 
114, in rmtree_errorhandler
func(path)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Zugriff verweigert: 
'c:\\users\\ravi\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-ta7sa2- 
uninstall\\users\\ravi\\anaconda2\\lib\\site- 
packages\\numpy\\core\\multiarray.pyd'
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Please post the traceback as text, it's unreadble.

Comment: @KlausD. did that. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your problem

Looks like your user doesn't have the permission to install packages in your system (for all users).

### Solution

From the Command Prompt, you can **install the package for your user only**, like this:

```
pip install <package> --user
```

***OR***

You can **install the package as Administrator**, by following these steps:

1. Run the Command Prompt as Administrator, using the `Run This Program As An Administrator` option.
2. Run the command `pip install <package>`